# Why can my unit test project not see a single method from another project? [.NET Framework]

Tags: .net, testing

I am trying to unit test a public method from my project, but am receiving the following error:

Code project:

```
public class Example
{
     private static object InstanceLock { get; } = new object();

     private static Example _instance = null;
     public static Example Instance
     {
          get
          {
              lock (InstanceLock)
              {
                   if (_instance == null) _instance = new Example();
              }
              return _instance;
          }     
     }

     public void Foo(obj param)
     {
          // do some stuff
     }
}
```

Test Project:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using CodeProject.Example;

[TestClass]
public class TestExample
{
     [TestMethod]
     public void FooTest()
     {
         Example example = Example.Instance;
         Object obj = new Object();

         example.Foo(obj);
        
         // assert to make sure it worked
     }
}
```

The error is coming from the example.Foo(obj) call in the test project. Intellisense does not detect it at all, and when I try to build I receive the following:

> 'Example' does not contain a definition for 'Foo' and no accessible extension method 'Foo' accepting a first argument of type 'Example' could be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)

Both projects are in the same solution and I am able to use other methods from the Example class. The strange thing is, when I build it without running, I receive the error, but when I run the test, it hits the method call correctly, enters it as it should, and the test passes.

Things I have tried:

1. Rebuilding both projects
2. Attempting to use other methods from the Example class
3. Double check all the using and access specifiers

Comment: Something seems broken in the build. Maybe try to delete your .suo file or .vs folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the test project .csproj file contains a "ProjectReference" XML element pointing at the code project, and not a "Reference" XML element. In the "Add Reference..." window in Visual Studio, this is the difference between adding a project reference or an assembly reference. If you add an assembly reference by mistake, dependencies may not get built or may be built in the wrong order because the relationship between the projects is unknown.

Also, right click the root node of your solution and click "Configuration Manager..." to verify that both projects get built in your active solution configuration.

Comment: I believe they were building out of order, hence why it would run correctly, but show an error on the build. It seems to be working now. Thanks.